# What is the best way to search 2 lists to compare values?

Tags: java, search

I have two lists, with one list containing one type of object/class and the second list, another type of object. However, the different objects have a common field whose value can provide a link between the two objects. So if this field is a string I would just compare the value of the string between the two different objects.

What is the best way to search the lists to compare the elements in the list to find which elements from the two lists have a link?

The simplest way is to use 2 loops but what is a more efficient way?

Comment: do these objects share a common parent class that contains the common attribute or are these objects two different classes that happen to have the same name for their respectable attribute?

Comment: Can there be more than one object in each list with the same value? If not, the fastest is to create a `Map` of value to object using one of the lists, then iterate the other list and lookup to find a match. If duplicate values can be present, then you first need to decide what should happen in that case, e.g. if first list has 2 objects with value "foo", and second list has 3 objects with value "foo", what should happen?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz. They do not share a common parent class. The name of the attribute is also different (or could be the same). It is the value of the attribute I am comparing. So the two classes are different but have a common link through the value of one of its fields.

Comment: @Andreas. Yes in one of the lists there can be multiple elements where the value of the field is the same. In the other list there can only be one element with that particular value.

Comment: @Mars Then build map using other list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming values in `list2` are unique, build a `Map` keyed by values from `list2`, then iterate `list1` to find matches:

```
Map<String, Class2> map2 = new HashMap<>();
for (Class2 obj2 : list2)
    if (map2.put(obj2.getValue(), obj) != null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate value in list2: " + obj2.getValue());
for (Class1 obj1 : list1) {
    Class2 obj2 = map2.get(obj1.getValue());
    if (obj2 != null) {
        // found match
    }
}
```